Facing "! Package tagpdf Error: there is no open structure on the stack" error when loading \usepackage{floatpag} in LuaLaTeX
I am getting an error: "Package tagpdf Error: there is no open structure on the stack" when I load the package floatpag in the document. Could you please advise how to solve the error? My MWE is below:
\DocumentMetadata{testphase={phase-III,table,pdfversion = 2.0}}
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{floatpag}

\begin{document}

The first section of this chapter consists of a brief and informal overview of the topics addressed in the book, in which only terms and notions familiar Body matter First column Footnote content with two lines. The first section of this chapter consists of a brief and informal overview of the topics addressed in the book from traditional grammar and/or introductory courses in morphosyntax are used. Section 1.2 discusses the position taken by the author about some concepts generally considered basic for the analysis of clause structure and its semantic correlates, and the terms used to refer to them. Section 1.3 presents the framework within which transitivity, valency, Opener Page Footnote text and voice are discussed in the remainder of the book.

\begin{table*}[!t]
\caption{Basic demographic characteristics of the 48 speakers who produced the stimuli Basic demographic characteristics of the 48 speakers who produced the stimuli Basic demographic characteristics of the 48 speakers who produced the stimuli}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep\fill}p{40pt}p{40pt}p{40pt}p{40pt}@{\extracolsep\fill}}%
\toprule
Dialect$_{AR}$ & Number of speakers$_{AR}$ & Mean age & Sex\\
\midrule
Gheg & 26 & 52 & 19 F, 7 M\\
Tosk & 22 & 42 & 14 F, 8 M\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table*}

The first section of this chapter consists of a brief and informal overview of the topics addressed in the book, in which only terms and notions familiar from traditional grammar and/or introductory courses in morphosyntax are used. Section 1.2 discusses the position taken by the author about some concepts generally considered basic for the analysis of clause structure and its semantic correlates, and the terms used to refer to them. Section 1.3 presents the framework within which transitivity, valency, Opener Page Footnote text and voice are discussed in the remainder of the book.

\end{document}

Error Message:


the package is currently incompatible. I added an issue https://github.com/latex3/tagging-project/issues/209 and will it also add to the tagging status table https://latex3.github.io/tagging-project/tagging-status/
